# Draw plot for category values in a plot have same coordinates

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, seaborn

Say category-->ram,sam,madhu

```
ram=np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
sam=np.power(ram,2)
madhu=np.arange(3,8,1)

x_axis=np.arange(1,10)
y_axis=np.arange(1,30)
```

Now, can I draw line chart for values of ram, sam, and Madhu in x_axis / y_axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could start by importing numpy and pyplot and then draw a [plot](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html). [Here](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/introductory/pyplot.html) is a tutorial to get started. A legend can be added by giving each plot a label and calling `plt.legend()`.

```py
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

ram = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
sam = np.power(ram, 2)
madhu = np.arange(3, 8, 1)

plt.plot(ram, sam, label='sam')
plt.plot(ram, madhu, label='madhu')
plt.xlim(0, 10)
plt.ylim(0, 30)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]